# Results from HttpGet are received after component is drawn

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I go about making sure that the function in this `switchMap` is executed after it is certain that the HTTP request is completed and all data is received?

Right now I am receiving the data after my element is drawn, which therefore doesn't show the results from the HTTP request.

Here the request is made:

```
 const request = this.outlookService.createMultipleCalendarEvents(calendarEvents);
        const infModal = request.pipe(
            switchMap((response : conflictingInterviewsDto) => this.createConflictingMeetingDialog(response))
        );

        this.modalDialogService.performUpdateOperation(this.modelState, () => infModal);
```

Here is the function used in the `switchMap`. It is responsible for rendering a modal with the data from the response.

```
  private createConflictingMeetingDialog(conflictingInterviews: conflictingInterviewsDto) : Observable<void>{
    this.listOfConflictingMeetings = conflictingInterviews.calendarEventsConflicting;
    const bob = document.getElementById('conflicting-meetings') as HTMLDivElement
    return of (this.modalDialogService.showElementBasedInformationModal(bob));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're being confused about how Angular works.

Angular dynamically updates the UI when the data you use is getting received. So, getting it after your view has been rendered should not be an issue.

Still, you can manage to wait for the data to be there before opening your component, but only if this component is routed (it is bound to an URL and you use routing in your application). Take a look at the [`Resolve`](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) interface and how it works, if you want to achieve this.

But about the data not being rendered on your page, the issue lies in the fact that your observable is not being subscribed to. An observable without observers does not trigger, hence making your data void.

Try writing this :

```js
const request = ...;
request.subcribe((result) => console.log(result));
```